# collection changed event using reactive extensions

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am trying to subscribe a collection to ViewModel using reactive extension

```
AllTags = tagList.ToObservable(Scheduler.ThreadPool);
```

and this is subscription

```
subscription = Model.GetAllEntities().Subscribe(x => RefreshAllEntities(x));
```

My question is that if something is added to tagList and call OnNext gives notification. But when i delete a item from collection how can be keep in sync. There is no notification. Kindly help.

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what you are asking. While I understand you are in general trying to monitor a collection on a view model using Rx, several aspects of your question are unclear. E.g. What is the type of `tagList`? How is it maintained? Should synchronization be bi-directional? Calling `ToObservable` on an `IEnumerable<T>` (or `List<T>`) merely iterates through the list pushing it into an observable stream. There is no tracking of updates. Please can you add detail to your question to phrase it more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `ToObservable<T>()` on an `IEnumerable<T>` does not result in any tracking of changes to underlying collection.

All `ToObservable<T>` does is obtain an enumerator from the source enumerable *on subscription*, and iterates through it pushing elements to the subscriber. That's it. No tracking of changes.

If you want to have a collection whose changes are reported to a view model, consider using a property of type `ObservableCollection<T>` on your view model. [MSDN has a small tutorial here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748365%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) This implements [`INotifyCollectionChanged<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which reports changes to collection and is often used as the `ItemSource` for lists and combo boxes.

Reactive Extensions is not required for this. However, it is commonly used with ObservableCollections in two distinct ways:

- To monitor and react changes to the collection made through the UI by subscribing to the `INotifyCollectionChanged<T>` events.
- To subscribe to an external source of updates and call Add/Remove on the ObservableCollection as appropriate; you must do this, there is no automatic wire-up of updates.

In both regards, [`ReactiveUI`](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/rxui6-master/docs/overview.md) is a framework you may wish to look at that provides some useful help here and enhanced alternatives to `ObservableCollection<T>`. The link provided is to the best (IMHO) overview which sits inside the source code repo. The sample projects are worth a look too. Unfortunately it's documentation isn't great, but the original author Paul Betts is very responsive to questions on Stack Overflow.

Another alternative for publishing changes from a source stream is to look at `DictionarySubject<T>` in the [Rxx](http://rxx.codeplex.com/) extensions to Rx - but this has a higher barrier to entry as there is even less documentation and currently Rxx hasn't had a published download/package compiled for new version of Rx for some time. Although you can do this yourself, it's not straightforward. It's a shame, because the implementation is pretty good. The author, Dave Sexton, has mentioned an intention for Rxx's best bits to be merged into Rx at some point - but there is no timeframe for this I am aware of.